# How do I manually trigger a delegated event with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Is there a way with jQuery to manually trigger an delegated event handler?

Take following example code:

```
<div class="container">
  <input type="button" value="Hello">
  <span class="output"></span>
</div>
​
<script>
  $('.container')
    .on('click', '[type=button]', function(e) {
      $(e.delegateTarget).find('.output').text($(this).val());
    })
    .find('[type=button]').triggerHandler('click');​
</script>
```

(Online: http://jsfiddle.net/TcHBE/)

I was expecting that this would work, and text "Hello" would appear in the span without actually clicking the button, but it doesn't.

I'm using `e.delegateTarget` inside the handler, because the `.ouput` element won't be in a known relationship to the button, other than some place inside the `.container`. That is why I'm using a delegated event handler in the first place.

**Update:**

Also I'm using `triggerHandler`, because the event has a default behaviour in the real code I don't want to trigger. (In the real code the event is the custom event `hide` of the [Bootstrap Modal plugin](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals), but I don't actually want to hide the modal when triggering the event handler on page load).

I could extract the handler into a named function and call it directly, but due to the use of `e.delegateTarget`, that would make the how construct more complicated.

Comment: Update your code to show the actual problem. It's not clear that you want to prevent other event handlers or the default action from happening.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You could create an Event object manually and set the `target` property accordingly to trick jQuery into thinking the event bubbled up.

```
var c = $('#container');

c.on('click', '[type=button]', function(e) {
    $(e.delegateTarget).find('span').text($(this).val());
});

var event = jQuery.Event('click');
event.target = c.find('[type=button]')[0];

c.trigger(event);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PCLFx/

Comment: Some months later I come back and actually need this myself ;-)

Comment: Way better than using skeezy undocumented APIs to retrieve the event handler function.

Comment: `Event.target Read only`

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

Comment: @AlekseyBykov we create an instance of Event ourselves, thus we control it. It is read only for events that the browser fire.

(jQuery.Event('click')) instanceof Event = > false

(jQuery.Event('click')) instanceof jQuery.Event => true

Comment: To save someone else several hours of frustration: if you are looking to trigger the handler for the `blur` event, you should use the `focusout` event instead, because blur does not bubble to the container.

Answer (score 2):

I know, this question is *ancient* but as I was stumbling over it while looking for an answer to another problem I thought I might as well share my slightly simpler approach here.

The idea is to simply create the event on the desired *target element* directly: `$(target_selector).trigger(event_type)` or - even shorter for standard events like "click" - do `$(target_selector).click()`, see my little fiddle below:

```js
$(function(){
 $('.container').on('click','button',function(){
  console.log('delegated click on '+$(this).text());
  return false;
 });
 $('#other').click(e=>$('.container button').trigger('click'));
 $('#clickone').click(e=>$('.container .one').click());
});
var btnNo=$(".container button").length;
$("#addbtn").click(e=>$(".container").append($(`<button class="one">button ${++btnNo}</button>`)));
```

```css
.one {background-color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addbtn">Add a red button</button>
<form class="container">
<button type="submit" class="one">click 1</button> and another chance to click here on <button class="two">click 2</button>.
</form><br>
<div id="other">Trigger clicks on all buttons in the`.container` div.</div><br>
<div id="clickone">Trigger a click on the red (`.one`) button(s) only.</div>
```

Comment: Delegated events do not require the elements to be present in DOM at the moment of binding. But your technique makes this presence compulsory. In that case, a delegated event is not even needed anymore (unless there are hundreds of targeted elements) – you could have made a binding of the original handler to the elements directly.

Comment: The direct binding in my snippet applies to a few (static) elements only (i. e. the two `<div>`s at the bottom). The "click" events on buttons inside the `.container` div are still handled as delegated events. They will be triggered on any (dynamically added) button there too. Try it out in my updated snippet.

Answer (score 1):

We can pass an additional `event configuration` to `jQuery's $.Event()` as the `second argument`.  More information [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

```js
$('#click-me').on('click', function(evt){
  $(document).trigger($.Event('custom-click', {target: evt.currentTarget}));
});

$(document).on('custom-click', '#click-me', function(evt){
  alert(`${evt.type} was triggered on button with ${evt.target.id} id.`);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="click-me">Click Me</button>
```

Good Luck...

Answer (score 0):

Selectors in the `.on()` method are optional.
When you write:

```
  $('.container')
    .on('click', '[type=button]', function(e) {
      $(e.delegateTarget).find('.output').text($(this).val());
    })
    .find('[type=button]').triggerHandler('click');​
```

You are telling the event handler to listen only to the button click inside the container.
`$(e.delegateTarget)` is just a reference to the outer container.

I've updated [your fiddle to echo this](http://jsfiddle.net/TcHBE/3/).

This is a quote [from the API:](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as
>   delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on
>   the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that
>   match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up
>   to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to
>   outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that
>   path matching the selector.

Comment: This edit may change the intent/purpose of his code. Including the selector `[type=button]` in this code will attach the event to buttons that are added to the DOM **after** page load. If he removes the selector, dynamically added buttons will not trigger the function when they are clicked.

Comment: @NoahWhitmore Thanks. That's an important mention. I used to forget all about the fourth dimension. :)

Answer (score 0):

As a complementary to @Prinzhorn's answer, it may be useful to have this JQuery function:

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.triggerParent = function (eventName, parent) {
        this.each(function() {
            var event = jQuery.Event(eventName);
            event.target = this;
            $(parent).trigger(event);
        });
    };
})( jQuery );
```