# jQuery: Why does .change() not trigger an event

Tags: jquery

I am putting some content read through ajax in a `div`.
The content has certain script tags which are used to bind some events on some element contained in the ajax content.

**Ajax Content:**

```
<div>
    <div>
        <select id='mySelectBox'>
            <option value="1">ONE</option>
            <option value="2" selected="selected">TWO</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).on("change",'#mySelectBox',function(){
            alert($('#mySelectBox').val());
         }); 
        $('#mySelectBox).change(); //problem here....
        </script>
</div>
```

The change event is bind and working correctly when i change the value of `'#mySelectBox'`.
But here in `$('#mySelectBox).change();` statement which triggers the change event immediately after it is bind is not getting called.

what might be the problem.?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are missing a closing quote. Try this instead:

```
$('#mySelectBox').change();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#mySelectBox).change();` does not trigger the event.

`$('#mySelectBox).trigger('change');` does. :)

`.change()` actually is a wrapper for `.on('change');`

UPDATE:

In case of a delegated event the .trigger() function won't bubble up.
A workaround can be found here:

[How do I manually trigger a delegated event with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724147/how-do-i-manually-trigger-a-delegated-event-with-jquery)

Comment: `.change()` does trigger the event. See the jQuery documentation - http://api.jquery.com/change/#change