# I'm trying to force mouseup event after mousedown

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

```
elements[0].onmousedown = function(){
      console.log('screen clicked.');
      simulatemouseuphere;
};
```

All I need to do is add something in my function that triggers mouseup, even if the user is holding the click button down.

> elements[0] is my entire page scope, so anywhere you click, it will trigger.

Comment: Have a look  -  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmousedown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can just call the onmouseup event...

```
elements[0].onmousedown = function(){
      console.log('screen clicked.');

      elements[0].onmouseup();
};
```

Keep in mind that when you actually physically stop holding the mouse down though, the mouseup event will be triggered again. (unless in the onmouseup() event you manage that)

Tested quickly, looks like it works:
http://jsfiddle.net/cUCWn/40/

Comment: That is doing exactly what I need. I can connect the dots from here, thank you so much.

Comment: I am getting returned an error of "Cannot read property 'onmouseup' of null. `function simMouseUp() {
  document.getElementById('keyboardBG').onmouseup();
}
function test() {
  console.log("Mouse is up!");
}`

Comment: if you are attempting to do this before the page has fully loaded it may be that your element does not yet exist (I'm assuming it's not that it doesn't find it because the ID is wrong) - without more info I'm afraid we might not be able to help much

Comment: This will only work if you set your handler using `element.onmouseup`, and if you are not using the event object in the handler. For something more robust see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click/2381862#2381862

Comment: You won't have access to original the event object inside the mouseup function.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but instead of firing a mouseup event, perhaps you want to trigger the function that is bound to the mouseup event?

```
var onMouseUp = function() { 
 /* something */  
};

var onMouseDown = function() { 
 /* something */ 
 onMouseUp.apply(this,arguments); 
};

elements[0].onmousedown = onMouseDown;
elements[0].onmouseup = onMouseUp;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").on("mousedown", function(e)
{
    e.type = "mouseup";
    $(this).trigger(e);
}).on("mouseup", function(e)
{
    console.info(e);
});
```

Or: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12724570/2625561

For pure JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Triggering_built-in_events

Comment: We don't know that abejdaniels is using jQuery, so this might not be helpful

Comment: Better, but this is essentially a link-only answer if you disregard the jQuery solution. You should try to give the key information from the link in your answer directly

Answer (score 0):

All the ways that are described here depend on how you set up the listener: jQuery, element property.

If you want a robust way that will work regardless of how the event was setup, use [How can I trigger a JavaScript event click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click/2381862#2381862)

```
elements[0].onmousedown = function(){
    fireEvent(elements[0], 'onmouseup');
};
```

Notice that you are probably better off wrapping the behavior of the mouseup handler into a function that you can call. Triggering handlers is usually code smell because you don't always know what else you may be triggering when firing events. For example:

```
function doSomethingOnMouseUp() {
    console.log('something on mouse up');
}

elements[0].onmousedown = function(){
    doSomething();
    doSomethingOnMouseUp();
};

elements[0].onmouseup = doSomethingOnMouseUp;
```